# Dependency between two classes

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

Is it possible to create something like "dependency" between two classes from different projects in one Eclipse. The point is that in both of this projects I need to have exactly the same class. I'd like to do something which allow me to make a changes in one of them and all the changes will automatically put in second. I hope that I explained it well ;)

Comment: That's called dependancy. Don't create clones.

Comment: are your projects web applications running in a web/application server?

Comment: First of them is regular Android project. Second is Dynamic Web Project based on Tomcat. Both projects are closely linked with each other through databases etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would-

1. Create a core project
2. Add core project to Project A
3. Add core project to Project B

Pretty much like how we use external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Create your common classes in a separate project. In eclipse set your build path for the other two projects to depend on your common project. When you release your projects, you build your common project as a separate jar and add it to the class path of your other projects.